# Поимка и обработка ошибок(Unique constraint) в GenericVIew

Tags: python, django, django-view

Если c обычными `View` всё ясно, то как поймать ошибку(`Unique Constraint`) и обработать в `UpdateView` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Переопредели метод update

2.from django.db import IntegrityError

3.Проделай операцию update под try:

4.Отлови с помошью:

```
except IntegrityError as e: 
    if 'unique constraint' in e.message:
```